# CSS selector for nth nested child

Tags: html, css

Is there a CSS selector to select the nth element with class "someclass" when the elements you need to match are "nested":

```
<div>
   <p><span></span></p>
   <p><span class="someclass"></span></p>
   <p><span></span></p>
   <p><span class="someclass"></span></p>
   <p><span class="someclass"></span></p>
   <p><span class="someclass"></span></p>
   <p><span></span></p>
   .
   .
   .
</div>
```

it's not possible to move the class to the the p tags unfortunately.

I've tried:

```
div p div.someclass:nth-child(2n)
div p div.someclass:nth-of-type(2n)
```

none seem to quite do exactly what I need.

Comment: div inside p is invalid to start with

Comment: Remove the extra colon from the `::nth-child` to `:nth-child` and `::nth-of-type` to `:nth-of-type`

Comment: good point @TemaniAfif , but I can't control that, it's generated from another system. I'm not sure it affects the answer to my question however. Make it any other valid tag inside. Let's say it's a span there.

Comment: There is currently no CSS selector for the nth instance of a class.

Comment: @CornelRaiu I tried this, it only works if every (in this case line of text) has it's span with "someclass". Some do not and I want to match the nth ones that do.

Comment: @Benjamin that is why I deleted the comment after you edited the post

Comment: Thanks @CornelRaiu, sorry it wasn't clear first time.

Comment: @Benjamin If you have no control over the markup, you should be aware that most browsers will probably automatically fix the invalid HTML and result in `<p></p><div>...</div><p></p>` rather than the `div` being a child of a `p`

Comment: I cannot think of any pure CSS method of doing this.

Comment: I'll point out that moving the class to the p tags wouldn't help for what you're trying to accomplish, as you'll still be trying to target the nth instance of a class.